# mongoose call model method from outside of express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose model file like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var testSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  username: { type: String },
  provider: { type: String },
  accessToken: { type: String },
  testId: { type: String }
});

/**Indexing*/
testSchema.index({ testId: 1, accessToken: 1 });

testSchema.statics = {

   get: function (id, callback) {
    this.findOne({'testId': id}, function(error, items){
        callback(error, items);
       });
   },
   create: function (data, callback) {
    var test = new this(data);
    test.save(callback);
   }
};

var test = mongoose.model('test', testSchema);

/** export schema */
module.exports = {
    Test: test
};
```

it is working Good with an express app. But I would like to use this model to view and insert data from command line. So, here is my approch which is not working

```
var Test = require('./app/model/test').Test;
Test.get({'testId': 1},function(err,res){
if(!err){
console.log(res);
}else{
console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a `mongoose.connect()` anywhere.

Comment: hi @robertklep, even if I add a connection but it don't work. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Can you specify what _"it don't work"_ actually means? Do you get errors? If so, please add them to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

- you're not calling `mongoose.connect()` anywhere, so it's not connecting to the database
- it looks like you should pass the id as an argument to `get()`; now you're passing it a query. Try this: `Test.get('1', ...)`

Comment: hi @robertklep , My directory structure is just like this --> 

+--> app
+--> server.js
+---> cmd.js

in app folder I have all models and controller and using ```node server.js``` I can use the app. I want to control my app from commandline so I created cmd.js where I am trying to calling mongoose model. 

Can you tell me how can I do this thing?